# При наведении курсора на часть карты должна менятся картинка

Tags: html, javascript

Пытаюсь создать подобие интерактивной карты, так что бы при наведении курсора на выделенный участок карты, менялась картинка:

```
<body>
<script language='javascript'>
    function changeImage1() {
        document.map.src = 'map_dfo.png';
    }

    function changeImage2() {
        document.map.src = 'rus_map.png';
    }
</script>
<img src="rus_map.png" alt="карта россии" usemap="#map" border="0" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="344,147,355,144," href="#" onmouseover='changeImage1()' onmouseout='changeImage2()'>
```

Если использовать скрипт без `<map>`, а только с картинкой, все работает идеально. Даже если в скрипте вместо document.map.src... подставить document.write("") - тоже работает идеально - при наведении курсора выводится надпись.

Уважаемые форумчане! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Почему картика не меняется?

Comment: TypeError: document.map is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может быть всё из за того что вы пытаетесь присвоить адрес картинки карте? попробуйте так:

1. задаем id изображению

   ```
    <img id="map" src="rus_map.png" alt="карта россии" usemap="#map" border="0" />
   ```
2. меняем в функции:

   ```
   function changeImage1() {
       document.getElementById('map').src = 'map_dfo.png';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Готовые интерактивные SVG карты России есть на http://fla-shop.com.ru

Comment: Вопрос не ограничен картами России.